# :include based on condition on included table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Client which has many :tours, association in it. I am using this code to provide all the clients with their tours,

```
render :json => Client.all(:include => :tours)
```

Now, the requirement has changed such that this object representation loads only tours of a user. Each tour is associated with an user with relation User has many :tours. I tried

```
render :json => Client.all(:include => :tours, :conditions => ["tours.user_id = ?", params[:user_id]])
```

This gives me the clients having tours of that user, but lists all the tours of these clients. But, I want only tours of that user only to be listed under each client. Can I do that using `:includes`?

client.rb

```
has_many :tours, :dependent => :destroy
```

user.rb

```
has_may :tours, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Update**

I thought it would be better to add an example to explain my problem. Suppose, there are 3 clients A, B, C.

- Client A has 3 tours (all of user user1)
- Client B has 4 tours (none of user user1)
- Client C has 3 tours (1 of user user1, others of other users)

Now if we use my method to get the response for user1, it will be like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Client A",
    ....
    "tours": [
      {
        "name": "Tour1",
        ....
      },
      {
        "name": "Tour2",
        ......
      },
      {
        "name": "Tour3",
        .....
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Client C",
    ....
    "tours": [
      {
        "name": "Tour4",
        ...
      },
      {
        "name": "Tour5",
        ...
      },
      {
        "name": "Tour6",
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can see that Client B has been omitted, and Client A and Client C has been included, which is correct. But, for Client C, only Tour5 belongs to user user1. But, it has all its tours included. I want my response to omit Tour5 and Tour6, like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Client A",
    ....
    "tours": [
      {
        "name": "Tour1",
        ....
      },
      {
        "name": "Tour2",
        ......
      },
      {
        "name": "Tour3",
        .....
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Client C",
    ....
    "tours": [
      {
        "name": "Tour4",
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I think, we need more information about your User model and it's relation to Client model :)

Comment: @Pavel there is no relation between User model and Client model...they are seperate entities and both has `has_many` relation between Tour model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only guessing but have you tried something along the lines of:

```
render :json => Client.all(:include => {:tours => :user}, :conditions => ["users.id = ?", params[:user_id]])
```

Comment: The `user_id` field is in `tours` table and not in `users` table. My problem is not the conditions. I have updated my question with an example.

Comment: Updated my example to fit. It should only include the given user... which means anything attached to any other user is simply removed form the set returned.

Comment: ok...got it...thank u so much...i failed to observe the `{:tours => :users}` part in your answer when you first posted it..just had to edit the `{:tours => :users}` to `:tours => :user` as a tour belongs to an user.